# How to make the custom xml layout for this project and works as righ now it is working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using [this demo Project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html) in My Application.

But here in this project there is a Dynamic layout created by the MyView Class.
Instead of that i want to Create the Custom Layout.

So How it is possible ?
Please Put Some XML code (And Java code if required to make the layout).
Thanks.

Edited:

I have Created the XML layout like this:

```
<view
        class="com.project.twsbi.FingerPaint$MyView"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:id="@+id/image"      
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

And as like the original project have set the resources in to FingerPaint class as like below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(new MyView(this)); // Edited
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // ste resources to View of Paint
    view = (View)findViewById(R.id.image);
    view = new MyView(this);
}
```

But Even doing that i am not able to paint as the original demo project do.
So Where i am Wrong ??

Comment: I am sure this question will be closed soon.

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239937/how-can-i-create-a-custom-layout-view-for-this-example/8240023#8240023) question was asked before also by someone else and was deleted by the moderators.

Comment: @LalitPoptani :I need help for this yaar.

Comment: I have google and try But not able to see any layout. . .  Let me updated My Question.

Comment: @Shrey Help will be provided when you help yourself. If I give the project Title on StackOverflow, will anyone do it for me?

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Ok I have Updated the Question. Please see it and if possible then help me. I have try my self but not get success thats why i have posted the question. Please Remove the negative reputation from me. Thanks.

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Please tell me now, Whats wrong in My code ? Why it is not going to work ?

Comment: @user370305 : I have try my self. Please see the Updated question. But i am not getting the resuls as the original demo project does. So Please help me for it.

Answer (score 1):

**First off** - You have to remove the line:

```
view = new MyView(this);
```

as it will just override the line:

```
view = (View)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

and the reference `view` will not be the one visible in your layout.

**Secondly** - To be able to use a custom `View` in a XML layout you will need to provide one of the constructors that include the `AttributeSet` e.g.:

```
public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet atrs ) {
    super(c, atrs);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}
```

Comment: I have just copy paste your code. but it not works.